# Unable to understand unet architecture

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I was trying to replicate UNET architecture but was having problems understanding why there is `16` written in the encoder part here:
[image]

Is this part of the architecture or should we need to choose it randomly? I understood it is the number of output channels of the conv layers but why `16`, not any other number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a design decision, so you won't find a clear reason for your question.

Other than that, the numbers in architecture are usually kept as multiple of `2`, here `2**4`. This is for practical reasons. It is usually the go-to method when testing variable-sized networks: they will try varying the numbers of layers, and numbers of channels as well as other network layouts and figure out which one is best for the task by experimenting.

---

By your first question,

> should we need to choose it randomly [...]?

Why would you not stick to the network's specification if you're looking to replicate it in the first place? If you ever find an advantage to putting `8` instead of `16`, or even `32` if you have the capacity to do so, then go right ahead!